# React Native Firebase v6, setBackgroundMessageHandler not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

Here is my code in index.js:

```
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async(remoteMessgae) => {
  console.log('Listening in Background ...')
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('isUserLoggedIn', 'false')
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    title: 'Test Title',
    message: 'Test Message' 
  })
})
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App)
```

Although i am getting notification in background/app closed, but console/AsyncStorage thing is not working.